# How can I find Maximum Common Subgraph of two graphs?

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

Hi i need a help in finding a graph algorithm

im working on the following  equation related to distance functions

```
d (g1, g2)   = 1-       │mcs(g1,g2) │  /
             │g1│+│g2│-│mcs (g1, g2) │
```

Where

- `d (g1,g2)` : is a distance function based on maximum common sub graph
  .
- `g1, g2` are two graphs .
- `mcs (g1,g2)`: is the maximum common sub graph of two graphs g1,g2
  where mcs is the largest graph (by some measure involving the number
  of nodes and edges )contained in both subject graphs .
- `│g1│`:  Cardinality of the common induced sub graph g1
- `│g2│`:  Cardinality of the common induced sub graph g2

**My Question:** How can I calculate MCS? 

I searched the internet but most of the algorithms are complicated anyone know from where i can get a simple algorithm to program this equation in matlab.

Comment: I'm going to ask what might be a silly question. You mention tracking a fleet of cars in the comments below. Is there any correspondence between the nodes of these graphs that is known beforehand? Something like "node A in both graphs is always the intersection of 4th and Main".

Comment: @ beaker ok the input for the distance function will be a gps data for cars movement i will represent this data as graph each node is the GPs location for the car at a certain time ... i will compare each daily car movement  vector with the other car graph in the same day i need mcs to find how much similar is the 2 journey in the same date .... hope the idea is more clear now ..thanks for the help

Comment: Knowing that the nodes of each graph represent geographical information reduces the complexity of the problem tremendously. Instead of an exponential search, as in the Clique Problem pointed out by @amit, you can use some distance metric to generate a correspondence between nodes and/or edges in polynomial time. I'll work up an answer with some strategies you can try to move forward, but if you've got any additional information beforehand, for instance a graph representing the map on which these cars move, that would help even more.

Comment: @beaker thanks for the explanation what other details you think its useful to make your suggestion  doable  cause i tried to search for an efficent algorithm couldnt find one

Comment: See my answer below, but here's a quick summary: Ideally you'd like to have a graph representing the map on which all of these routes occur. It would probably make more sense to model sections of road (city blocks, stretches of highway between on/off ramps, etc.) as nodes rather than edges. It would also be helpful to know the frequency of the gps updates, i.e. the number of nodes you can expect to pass through before the next update.

Answer (score 6):

**The problem is [NP-Complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete)**<sup>1</sup>.

The reduction from the [Clique Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem)<sup>2</sup>. Given an instance of Clique Problem - a graph `G=(V,E)`, create a complete [clique](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_%28graph_theory%29) `G'=(V,E')` such that `E' = {(u,v) | u != v, for each u,v in V)`.

The solution to the maximal clique problem is the same solution for the maximal subgraph problem for G and G'. Since clique problem is NP-Hard, so does this problem.

Thus, **there is no known polynomial solution** to this problem.

If you are looking for an exact algorithm, you could try [exhaustive search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_search) approach and/or a [branch & bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound) approach to solve it. Sorry for the bad news, but at least you know not to look for something that (probably) doesn't exist (unless [P=NP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem), of course)

---

**EDIT:** exponential brute force solution to the problem:

You can just check all possible subsets, and check if it is a feasible solution.

Pseudo Code:

```
findMCS(vertices,G1,G2,currentSubset):
  if vertices is empty: //base clause, no more candidates to check
      if isCommonSubgraph(G1,G2,currentSubset):
         return clone(currentSubset)
      else:
         return {}
  v <- vertices.pop() //take a look at the first element
  cand1 <- findMCS(vertices,G1,G2,currentSubset) //find MCS if it is NOT in the subset
  currentSubset.append(v)
  if isCommonSubgrah(G1,G2,currentSubset): //find MCS if it is in the subset
     cand2 <- findMCS(vertices,G1,G2,currentSubset)
  currentSubset.remvoe(v) //clean up environment before getting back from recursive call
  return (|cand1| > |cand2| ? cand1 : cand2) //return the maximal subset from all candidates
```

Complexity of the above is `O(2^n)` (checking all possible subsets), and invoke it with: `findMCS(G1.vertices, G1, G2, [])` (where `[]` is an empty list).

**Note:**

- `isCommonSubgrah(G1,G2,currentSubset)` is an easy to calculate method that just answers true if and only if `currentSubset` is a common subgraph of G1 and G2.
- |cand1| and |cand2| is the sizes of these lists.

---

(1)Assuming that Maximum sub graph is a subset `U` in `V` such that for each `u1,u2` in `U` `(u1,u2)` is in `E1` if and only if `(u1,u2)` is in `E2` (intuitively, a maximal subset of the vertices that share the exact same edges in the two graphs)

(2) Clique Problem: Given an instance of `G=(V,E)` find maximal subset `U` in `V` such that for each `u1,u2` in `U` : `u1 = u2` or `(u1,u2)` is in `E`.

Comment: i need this to calculate how much is 2 graphs is similar in two trajectories ...so you mean there is no specific algorithm to calculate MCS !!!

Comment: @fidam I mean there is no known *efficient* algorithm to calculate MCS, sorry for the bad news. brute force algorithms that check all subsets will find the maximal common subgraph, but for large graphs will just consume too much time to be feasible I am afraid.

Comment: im not concerened on complexity or time consuming i only need an algorithm to calculate the MCS,i just cant find a direct algorithm for mcs

Comment: @fidam What is the size of your graph? For larger then 50 nodes a branch and bound solution is just not feasible.

Comment: i will use the graph structure to represent  one day journy for a certain car movement ...im not expert in graph theory

Comment: @fidam I just added a pseudo code for an exponential solution. For small graphs it will find your MCS, for too large graphs it will just consume too much time (hundreds and thousands of years possibly).

Comment: that mean if i have a large fleet of cars i cant work with this algo am i  wright it will take alot of time ...mmmm so how can i solve this im stuck now ...i really appreciate your help

Comment: do you have any MCS algorithm that they explain  in text books in graph theory topics "not the  optimal algo that papers discuss the one in books  " cause i tried to search that in some texts books but find nothing related mybe im searching the wrong topic or title do u have any idea from where to get the mcs that studeied in university text books ?  ... some ppl told me you can find the original MCS in texts books

Comment: I am not sure I am following, are you looking for an [approximation algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_algorithm) now? There could be one, but I am not familiar with it. Note that approximation algorithms does not guarantee you a maximal common subgraph - it only gives a subgraph that is "close enough" to the true maximal. (As I said, not familiar with one, but this doesn't mean one does not exist). If you are looking for it - it is a different question IMHO, and should be asked in a different thread (that links to this one as "related")

Comment: The definition of subgraph is a very special one, making the problem hard. I can't find a hint in the original question that such a definition is actually intended.

Comment: @JensSchauder though I cannot reference this, I've seen a few times where the definition subgraph is used as a subset of vertices. If this is not what the OP is after all bets are off obviously, it is a different question. The answer applies for my understanding of what a subgraph is (which is explicitly mentioned in the answer as well).

Comment: i will input 2 paths (car journy in same day ) this is the graph ... subgraph will be how many vertices in the 2 paths of 2 cars in the  same day are similar

Comment: @beaker thanks for the explanation what other details you think its useful to make your suggestion  doable  cause i tried to search for an efficent algorithm couldnt find one in the litretures

Comment: @amit, can you explain how you are using "vertices" in your pseudocode above? It is not clear to me what this variable's role is in this algorithm.

Comment: @areyoujokingme It's the list of all current vertices. You go on the vertices one by one, checking if it should or should not be in the subgraph recursively. `vertices` is basically, at each point, the set of vertices that were not checked yet (which you don't know if they should or should not be in the best subgraph)

Comment: Aha @amit, so if I'm interpreting things correctly, vertices at initialization of the call to findMCS(...) will contain *all unique vertices* from both graphs G1 and G2, and currentSubset will be empty. By the end of the algorithm, currentSubset will be the MCS and vertices will be empty. Is that correct?

Comment: @amit, either I'm interpreting your pseudocode wrong or the logic is off. I suspect it is the former. I wrote an R script using your logic, and it just doesn't make sense to me. Am I interpreting things differently? Here is a pastebin: http://pastebin.com/0PQQ2LPA

Comment: @areyoujokingme I am not familiar with R, but the idea is simple, for each vertex "guess" if it's in the maximum common subgraph or not. By "guess" I mean first try one possibility, recurse and then try the other. This is an exhaustive search that is right by definition, because you check all subgraphs.

Answer (score 3):

The backtracking search algorithm proposed by [James J. McGregor](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/ed10/c6f788922cd5e7cb26c3d55f676979958852.pdf) may be utilized to identify the MCS between two graphs.

Answer (score 0):

You can't even check if one graph is a subgraph of the other one, it's the [subgraph isomorphism problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgraph_isomorphism_problem) known to be NP-complete. Hereby you can't find the maximal subgraph because you can't check the isomorphism property (in polynomial time).

Comment: this is only true if you assume that you are actually looking for isomorphic subgraphs, which isn't mentioned in the original question. If the nodes in the graph have 'identity' i.e. that you can check if it is or isn't part of a graph it becomes a completely different problem.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is finding a correspondence between nodes in the original graphs (essentially a renumbering of the vertices). For instance, if we have node *p* in graph *g1* and node *q* in graph *g2* where *p* and *q* are equivalent, we'd like to map them to a node *s* in the common subgraph, *c*.

The reason that the Clique Problem is so difficult is that, without any way of checking whether two nodes in different graphs actually refer to the same node, we have to try all possible combinations of pairs of nodes and check if each pair is consistent and represents the "best" correspondence.

Since the nodes in these graphs represent geographic locations, we should be able to come up with a reasonable distance metric that tells us how likely it is that a node in one graph is the same as any node in the other graph. Since the GPS coordinates of the two nodes are probably not identical, we need to make some assumptions based on the problem.

- If we have a map of the region in which the data points occur, represented as a graph *m*, we can renumber or rename the nodes in *g1* and *g2* to correspond to their closest equivalent in in *m*.
- Distance (either between the original graphs and *m* or between points in *g1* and *g2*) can either be the Euclidean distance or the Manhattan distance, depending on what makes more sense for your graphs.
- You'll have to be careful in deciding how far apart two nodes can be and still be considered equivalent. Too small and you won't get any matches; too large and your entire graph could be condensed into one node.
- Two or more nodes in an original graph could possible all map to the same node in *c*. If the location data is updated frequently in relation to the distance between nodes, for instance.
- Conversely, an edge between a pair of successive nodes in an original graph could also map to a path containing multiple edges if the update frequency is low in relation to the distances. So you'll have to figure out whether it makes sense to introduce these intermediate nodes into the common graph or treat the whole path as a single edge.

Once you've got the renumbering of the nodes you can use the method that Jens suggests to find the intersection of the renumbered graphs. This is all very general since I don't have a lot of details about your specific problem, but hopefully it's enough to get you started.