# Maximum Common Subgraph in a Directed Graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, networkx

I am trying to represent a group of sentences as a directed graph where one word is represented by one node. If a word is repeated then the node is not repeated, the previously existing node is used. Let's call this graph `MainG`.

Following this, I take a new sentence, creating a directed graph of this sentence (call this graph `SubG`) and then looking for the Maximum Common Subgraph of `SubG` in `MainG`.

I am using NetworkX api in Python 3.5. I understand that as this is NP-Complete problem for normal graphs, but for Directed Graphs it is a Linear problem. One of the links I referred:

[How can I find Maximum Common Subgraph of two graphs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643948/how-can-i-find-maximum-common-subgraph-of-two-graphs)

I tried to do the following code:

```
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd
import nltk

class GraphTraversal:
    def createGraph(self, sentences):
        DG=nx.DiGraph()
        tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(sentences)
        token_count = len(tokens)
        for i in range(token_count):
            if i == 0:
                continue
            DG.add_edges_from([(tokens[i-1], tokens[i])], weight=1)
        return DG


    def getMCS(self, G_source, G_new):
        """
        Creator: Bonson
        Return the MCS of the G_new graph that is present 
        in the G_source graph
        """
        order =  nx.topological_sort(G_new)
        print("##### topological sort #####")
        print(order)

        objSubGraph = nx.DiGraph()

        for i in range(len(order)-1):

            if G_source.nodes().__contains__(order[i]) and G_source.nodes().__contains__(order[i+1]):
                print("Contains Nodes {0} -> {1} ".format(order[i], order[i+1]))
                objSubGraph.add_node(order[i])
                objSubGraph.add_node(order[i+1])
                objSubGraph.add_edge(order[i], order[i+1])
            else:
                print("Does Not Contains Nodes {0} -> {1} ".format(order[i], order[i+1]))
                continue


obj_graph_traversal = GraphTraversal()
SourceSentences = "A series of escapades demonstrating the adage that what is good for the goose is also good for the gander , some of which occasionally amuses but none of which amounts to much of a story ."
SourceGraph = obj_graph_traversal.createGraph(SourceSentences)

TestSentence_1 = "not much of a story"    #ThisWorks
TestSentence_1 = "not much of a story of what is good"    #This DOES NOT Work
TestGraph = obj_graph_traversal.createGraph(TestSentence_1)

obj_graph_traversal.getMCS(SourceGraph, TestGraph)
```

As I am trying to do a topological sort, the second one doesn't work.

Would be interested in understanding the possible approaches to this.

Comment: What exactly fails? It seems likely that your tokenization is producing repeated data ('of') and so it might succeed if you took steps to ensure the data was unique. You might consider graphing pairs of `(index, token),` for example, where index was just the 0-based index of the token. (`for i,tok in enumerate(tokens): ...`)

Comment: @Austin Hastings Thank you for the response. The graph that gets created is cyclical and it would be that way as words in a sentence can be repeated. It is the same in the SourceGraph, we have cycles in that as well. Keeping that in mind we have to find the Maximum Common Subgraph.

Comment: I am a bit dense today. Why do you need the topological sort? Why can't you just filter for common edges and then compute the largest connected component?

Comment: @Paul thank you for the thought / comment. It got me thinking. Have posted my solution.

Comment: Hilarious. That was before the first coffee of the day, so I was really not trusting my thought process. Glad it helped.

Comment: What if there is more than 2 input graphs, is there a solution to find maximum common subgraph from 3 or more input (directed )graphs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code gets the maximum common subgraph from a directed graph:

```
def getMCS(self, G_source, G_new):
    matching_graph=nx.Graph()

    for n1,n2,attr in G_new.edges(data=True):
        if G_source.has_edge(n1,n2) :
            matching_graph.add_edge(n1,n2,weight=1)

    graphs = list(nx.connected_component_subgraphs(matching_graph))

    mcs_length = 0
    mcs_graph = nx.Graph()
    for i, graph in enumerate(graphs):

        if len(graph.nodes()) > mcs_length:
            mcs_length = len(graph.nodes())
            mcs_graph = graph

    return mcs_graph
```

Comment: I got this error: `AttributeError: module 'networkx' has no attribute 'connected_component_subgraphs'`. I'm using NetworkX 2.4.

Comment: @Tonechas in case you still need a solution, replace the error-inducing line with
`graphs = list(matching_graph.subgraph(c) for c in networkx.connected_components(matching_graph))`

Answer (score 1):

The edit queue for Bonson's answer is full, but it doesn't work with networkx 2.4 anymore and has some possible improvements:

- `connected_component_subgraphs` was removed in networkx 2.4 and `connected_components` which returns a set of nodes should be used instead.
- because only the number of nodes is to find the largest component this can be simplified significantly.
- this isn't specifically tailored to the initial question anymore, because this is the best hit if searching for "Maximum Common Subgraph in a Directed Graph" which I needed for something completely different

My adapted version is:

```py
def getMCS(g1, g2):
    matching_graph=networkx.Graph()

    for n1,n2 in g2.edges():
        if g1.has_edge(n1, n2):
            matching_graph.add_edge(n1, n2)

    components = networkx.connected_components(matching_graph)

    largest_component = max(components, key=len)
    return networkx.induced_subgraph(matching_graph, largest_component)
```

If the last line is replaced with `return networkx.induced_subgraph(g1, largest_component)` it should also work correctly and return a directed graph.